# Is there any way to connect docker mysql from host?

Tags: mysql, docker

I created mysql docker container

```
docker run -p 13306:3306 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="pass" -e MYSQL_DATABASE="db" --name mysql mysql:5.6.46
```

and I tried to connect to mysql

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 13306
```

but I can't connect to mysql.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I must connect like this for some reason. not use `docker exec -i -t mysql bash`

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

you should try and expand your question a bit and add some more information about the errors you receive.

In my local development environment in order to connect to my MySQL database I give it a static ip address. I tend to use docker-compose and not run it from the docker command directly for simplicity. This is what my docker-compose.yaml file looks like for a mariaDB container :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  maria:
    container_name: maria
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: always
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
     - MYSQL_USER=user
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password
    volumes:
     - ./maria:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      static:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.10

networks:
  static:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
       - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16
```

After running the *docker-compose up* command I can now connect to the mysql shell with the command

```
mysql -uuser -puser_password -h 172.30.0.10
```

if you are running linux you can also add a line to your /etc/hosts file like :
172.30.0.10 mysql

you can then connect with the command

```
mysql -uuser -puser_password -h mysql
```

I'm pretty confident you can get the same results with a pure docker command but it just seems easier with docker-compose. Anyway I hope ths helps